# Examples of analytic fiber space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Let $\Delta$ be a non-singular curve (i.e a compact Riemann surface). 
>   We say that $V$ is an analytic fiber space of curves of genus $\pi$
>   over $\Delta$ if there exists a holomorphic map $\Phi$ of $V$ onto
>   $\Delta$ such that the inverse image $C_u = \Phi^{-1}(u)$ of any
>   general point $u$ of $\Delta$ is a non-singular irreducible curve of
>   genus $\pi$.
>
> Let $\pi=1$. For any $a \in \Delta$, we  denote by $\tau_a$ the local
>   uniformization variable on $\Delta$ with the center $a$ and by
>   $\tau_a(u)$ the value of $\tau_a$ at a point $u$ in a neighborhood of
>   $a$ on $ \Delta$.
>
> we call $C_u := \Phi^{-1}(u)$  a regular fiber space if
>   $\frac{\partial \Phi(\tau_a(z))}{\partial {z^1}}+\frac{\partial
> > \Phi(\tau_a(z))}{\partial {z^2}} =0$ at each point $z$ on
>   $\Phi^{-1}(u)$, where $(z_1,z_2)$  is a system of local coordinates on
>   $V$.
>
> By the singular fiber $C_{a_\rho}$ of $V$ over $a_\rho$, we mean the
>   devisor of the holomorphic function $\tau_{a_\rho}(\Phi)$. We write
>   each singlura fiber $C_{a_\rho}$ in the form
>
> $ C_{a_\rho} = \sum _s n_{\rho,s}\Theta_{\rho,s}$
>
> where $n_{\rho,s}$ i are positive integers and $\Theta_{\rho,s}$ are
>   irreducible curves.

The non-singular fiber is classified in six cases, one of which is e.g. the following.

> $C_{a_\rho} = \Theta_1 + \Theta_2 +\Theta_3,$ where $\Theta_1,
>  \Theta_2,\Theta_3$  are non-sigular rational curves and  $\Theta_s $
>   and $\Theta_t$ meats at a single point for $s \neq t$.

I cannot understand. I cannot make a example of such $V$. Someone  have idea or example of such $V$?

Comment: Your question is not so clear to me. Which of the following are you looking for? i) an example of "analytic fibre space of curves" (ii) an example of "analytic fibre space of curves of genus 1" (iii) an example as in (ii) but with a fibre of the specific type you mention?

Comment: Also where you wrote "non-singular fiber" you appear to mean "singular fibre".

Comment: I want to obtain any example. I want to get (iii).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the question as asking for a morphism $f: S \rightarrow C$ from an algebraic surface to an algebraic curve such that:

- for a general point $p \in C$ the fibre $f^{-1}(p)$ is a smooth curve of genus 1;
- there exists a point $q \in C$ such that the fibre $f^{-1}(q)$ is a union of 3 rational curves meeting pairwise at a point.

My favourite example is the so-called *Hesse pencil* of cubic curves. Start with the family of cubic plane curves

$$ C_{\lambda, \mu} := \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbf P^2 \mid \lambda (x^3+y^3+z^3) - \mu xyz = 0\}.$$

This family gives a rational map $\mathbf P^2 \rightarrow \mathbf P^1$; explicitly it is written as $$ (x,y,z) \mapsto [xyz,x^3+y^3+z^3].$$

This map is defined away from the base locus of the pencil, meaning the set $C_{1,0} \cap C_{0,1}$.

**Exercise**: show this set consists of 9 reduced points.

Blowing up the 9 points, we get a morphism $S \rightarrow \mathbf P^1$ whose fibre over $[\lambda,\mu] \in \mathbf P^1$ is isomorphic to the curve $C_{\lambda,\mu}$.

In particular the fibre over the point $[0,1]$ is the curve $xyz=0$ which is a triangle of lines in $\mathbf P^2$, as you want.

Comment: Because $C_{0,1} \cap C_{1,0}=\{(1:\pm{1}:0),  (1:0:\pm{1}),(0:1:\pm{1}) \} $ and trivial excluded point $(0:0:0)$, I think the "reduced point" is 7 points. (I am not sure the precise definition of the base locus or reduced points.) I cannot found 9 points, but I found 7 points. I am not sure why blowing up are used.  I guess the reason why bowing up are used is that the rational map is not a map, so by blowing up the rational map, we can get a morphism. Is it correct?

Comment: You found 3 of the 9 points, with coordinates like $[1,-1,0]$. A point like $[1,1,0]$ is not on the curve $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$, and as you said, $[0,0,0]$ is not a point in the plane. You are missing points like $[\omega,-1,0]$ where $\omega=\exp(2 \pi i/3)$. Yes, blowing up is used precisely to turn the rational map into a morphism.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I understand that the solution of $X^3=1$ is $\omega$.....Oh no :`-D. So, the intersection is $C_{0,1} \cap C_{1,0}= \{(1:\omega^n:0),(1:0:\omega^n),(0:1:\omega^n) ; n=1,2,3\}$. Is there any good book which explains your example? I am very beginner of algebraic geometry.